# How to remove the column in group by

Tags: sql, group-by

I am working on a query where I want `MG.Actid` to appear as a `SELECT` column but not within a `group by` because it is not listing the results that I want. The group structure is getting spoiled if I have it in `group by`. Please let me know how to retain it in select column and remove it from `group by`.

Want the `group by` only for `SR.Rsrcid`, `sr.frsntnm`, `sr.lstm`

Query :

```
SELECT
(SR.LstNm+ ', '+ SR.FrstNm) as 'Employee Name',
 MG.Actid as goalid,
 SR.Rsrcid as EmpID,
 COUNT(Mg.ActID) '# Goals',
 SUM(CASE
       WHEN PrntActID != '' THEN 1
       ELSE 0
     END) AS '# Aligned'
FROM   TM.SResource AS SR 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TM.MatrixGoal AS Mg  
        ON SR.RsrcID = MG.RsrcID AND MG.DelFlg = 0
WHERE  MG.ActiveFlg = 1
GROUP  BY SR.RsrcId,SR.LstNm,SR.FrstNm
ORDER BY SR.LstNm,SR.FrstNm
```

Comment: To have it in the SELECT list without including it in the GROUP BY, you must put it in an aggregate function like MAX() or MIN().

Comment: Please edit your question and provide sample data and desired results.  The obvious answer to your question is to use an aggregation function, such as `MAX(mg.ActId)`.

Comment: You are already doing that in your query by grouping only those required field so what is the issue you are facing? and add your sample data and expected output

Comment: The reason that the select list in an aggregate query may only contain functions of the groups (including the grouping columns themselves) and values altogether independent of the groups is that those are the only values that are well-defined on a per-result-row basis.  In other words, since `MG.Actid` is not a grouping column, different rows in each group may have different values for that column, so you must specified which one of those you want.

Comment: Also, do be aware that your filter predicate on the inner table of your outer join  (`WHERE  MG.ActiveFlg = 1`) effectively turns the outer join into an inner join.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to use the 'partition by' clause in your aggregate functions (like SUM and COUNT), and then select the distinct rows from your data set.  Effectively, you move the group by statement to a partition for each aggregate, like this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
(SR.LstNm+ ', '+ SR.FrstNm) as 'Employee Name',
 MG.Actid as goalid,
 SR.Rsrcid as EmpID,
 COUNT(Mg.ActID) OVER (PARTITION BY SR.RsrcId,SR.LstNm,SR.FrstNm) '# Goals',
 SUM(CASE
       WHEN PrntActID != '' THEN 1
       ELSE 0
     END) OVER (PARTITION BY SR.RsrcId,SR.LstNm,SR.FrstNm) AS '# Aligned'
FROM   TM.SResource AS SR 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TM.MatrixGoal AS Mg  
        ON SR.RsrcID = MG.RsrcID AND MG.DelFlg = 0
WHERE  MG.ActiveFlg = 1
ORDER BY SR.LstNm,SR.FrstNm
```